# Lambda function: how to solve asynchronus issue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Lambda function on AWS, and code is written in Nodejs
I have an issue with Asynchronus. here is my issue :

- I have an 4 records of users
- I want to get other details and invoke other lambda for each user
- what i am doing is, i make loop for each users
- then in the loop, i am trying to invoke other lambda function.

Consigder, my code is :

```
(allProblems).forEach( function(eachProblem){
  console.log("User:"+eachProblem.userId)
  /*Lambda invoke */
  lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'invitationHandler',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(params, null, 2) // pass params
    }, function(error, data) {
      /* Code For update data in another table */
     console.log("Data saved");
    }
  })
```

current output is :

```
User: 1
User: 2
Data saved
User: 3
Data saved
User: 4
Data saved
```

Expected Output :

```
User: 1
Data saved
User: 2
Data saved
User: 3
Data saved
User: 4
Data saved
```

Please help me to get this solved...
Thanks

Comment: I think you should use InvocationType: 'RequestResponse'. Actually, RequestResponse is the default invocation type. Try to mention that specifically and check the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await node functionnality to manage your asynchronous call.

Check documentation : https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

1. define your function as 'async'.
2. use await

For example with your code, try something like :

```
try {
  (allProblems).forEach(function(eachProblem) {
    console.log("User:"+eachProblem.userId) 
    /*Lambda invoke */ 
    var data = await lambda.invoke({ FunctionName: 'invitationHandler', Payload: JSON.stringify(params, null, 2) // pass params }) console.log("Data saved")
  }
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick resonse :
Can you able to rewrite code for the same which i have written above ?

Comment: Which function, i need to make async ?

Comment: the function where your forEach is present

Comment: I am not getting proper result if use async. Can you please rewrite my code with async